# Pandas doesn't return the correct number while adding values in cells

Tags: python, pandas

I got the raw dataset from https://www.kaggle.com/gustavomodelli/forest-fires-in-brazil

Acre_dataset is the sub-dataset of the raw dataset [Acre_dataset](https://github.com/610yilingliu/trouble_data)

I am trying to sumup the values in column "number" filtered by different values in "year" column like the following screenshot

The dataset Acre_dataset contains about 300 rows and the precision of values in column "number" are all below 0.001 (which means we will not have numbers like 1.0001, but we will have numbers like 1.001)
[image]

Code in screenshot:

```
Acre_firecount = [0] * len(year_ls)
print(type(Acre_dataset.iloc[0]['number']))
for i in range(len(Acre_dataset)):
    for j in range(len(year_ls)):
        if Acre_dataset.iloc[i]['year'] == year_ls[j]:
            Acre_firecount[j] += Acre_dataset.iloc[i]['number']
print(Acre_firecount)
type(Acre_firecount[12])
```

But I got two rare numbers in this list, which are 475.21299999999997 and 618.4300000000001.

I already checked the datatype of numbers in cells in column "number" in Acre_dataset and the datatype of elements in list Acre_firecount(Which is the outcome), they are all numpy.float64.

Why did this kind of problem occours and how to aviod it?

Comment: Please provide a copy of the data and not a screenshot of the data, this makes it easier to reproduce.

Comment: It's a known issue in `python` floating representation system (not `pandas` fault). Use `Acre_dataset['number'] = Acre_dataset['number'].round(3)` to force it to 3 digits accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

I found the explanation in [Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)

it said:

***Python only prints a decimal approximation to the true decimal value of the binary approximation stored by the machine***